# What's the advantage of using (.) instead of ($)?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I want to define `odd` in Haskell. How I would go about it is of course `not . even`. However, that's exactly the same as `not $ even` or `not (even)`. What's the advantage of using `(.)` instead of one of the other two options? I know it's encouraged, but I don't know why exactly.

Comment: This is incorrect, I suggest you test those in GHCi, especially `not (even)`. `not . even $ x` *happens* to work the same as `not $ even $ x`, but that's just an accident of precedence: the latter is parsed as `not $ (even $ x)`.

Comment: As they say in the vernacular, "not even!"

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think is a duplicate.....

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Even if the example is incorrect, I would also like to know why the dot is encouraged. I think is a good question.

Comment: It's function composition, gives more mathematical flavor and enables talking about functions without values (points).

Comment: @dsign, see [What is a canonical question/answer and what is their purpose?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose).

Comment: @dfeuer Ah, but it is a duplicate of the one given by Sam!

Comment: @dsign I guess it is, although I'm not sure I agree Don's top-voted answer is the best one.